# I have cloned my main diskdrive by dd but

Tags: fedora, boot, dual-boot, dd, live-usb

**Step 1:** I have cloned my main diskdrive by dd cmd: `bash -c "dd if=/dev/sda |pv| gzip > /media/disk/sda-backup.gz"`

**Step 2:** Now I like to make the cone work running from USB stik. I have a 120Gb usb stick and the old hhd are 80Gb.

I then used below cmd:

```
gunzip -c /media/disk/sda-backup.gz |pv -pter -s 80g | dd of=/dev/sdc bs=64K
```

**Step 3:** bootup on the usb stick on another computer then the original........ here is the problem, the boot looks fine to start with choosing the Fedora (2.6.27.25-78.2.56.fc9.i686)

When booting I get the problem/error with Red Hat showing in the attached picture.

[image: Bootup problem RedHat / physical volumes]

If I boot the usb stick on the original computer then its works fine. So I assume, that I need to change somewhere(???) the boot files / location is on another location then the physical volumes...

Comment: It would have been FAR FAR faster to have not used `dd` at all, but to have run `pv </dev/sda | gzip > /media/disk/sda-backup.gz`

Answer (score 0):

Put `usb-storage` module (and its all dependencies) into initrd.

Comment: can you explan how, I assume you mean the file 
initrd-2.6.27.25-78.2.56.fc9.i686.img and thats a binary file, im not sure how to add usb-storage module...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have a LVM setup on the original computer where VolGroup00 contains the LogVol01 volume which is your actual root device.

The physical device where that volume group resides is probably not the origin device (/dev/sda) you copied with `dd`.

That's why it does not work on your other computer, only on the original one.

What you could do is copy the root files from /VolGroup00/LogVol01 (whatever that is) to your stick and change the `root=` kernel option to the new location, e.g. `/dev/sda1`.

Look at the output of `sudo pvs` to find out which physical device contains the VolGroup00 group.

Comment: modprobe dm-mod

vgchange -ay
then i can mount:
mount /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /mnt/
inside i can see the files are there. But how do I change root= kernel option? maybe that could do the trick. I assume there is somewhere that is says sda and i need to thange that to sdb (usbstick)?

Comment: You can change the kernel options in the grub.cfg file in /boot/grub. But currently it is set to `/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01` and that device cannot be found... You could try to provide more information (disk layout, LVM setup), that would be helpful.